# How to hide a product in magento2 rest api?

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

I want the product not to appear on the site, but not delete ?

How to do it through the REST API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the status of your product to disabled through Rest Api. That will make in hidden from appearing in website.

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: simple and to the point. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @ShoaibMunir